# How to implement Revolution Slider Duotone hover effect

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css, parallax, revolution-slider

I have been working on a site and trying to copy the hover effect of Duotone from revolution slider.
- https://revolution.themepunch.com/wordpress-duotone-effect-add-on/

I can't seem to figure out how to apply the hover effect to my test site. I wanted the same hover effect from Duotone main slider to my test site main banner.
 - http://ittiz2.qadracreatives.com/

Any advice or help will be appreciated. More Power

NOTE: I will not be using the slider revolution plugin, but I will just "replicating" the effect on horizontal parallax scroll.

Actually, I've already found a code but the effect is broken, here's the code that I've copied: pastebin.com/raw/Jc9Apavi

Answer (score 0):

The hover effect can be accomplished by the following steps:

1. put the elements on the same slider into different groups. In this case, I would put the front texts into one group. The surrounding elements (those triangles) into a second group. The seemly very far away (blurred) elements into a third group. To put them into different groups, you can either put their dom elements into 3 different arrays or simply give the elements inside each group a different css class, such as `group-1`, `group-2` and `group-3`. Or you can organize the elements in the same group and wrap them using a parent `div`. The following steps assumes the parent div approach.
2. after the page loads, calculate the position of the center of the slide. You may need to recalculate when you detect window resize events. The calculation itself is simple. We use the left top corner of the slider as the origin. Effectively, we use the slide as a Cartesian coordinate system and the origin is the left top corner. Now the center position is just `(slider_width / 2, slider_height / 2)`. You can cache the center position.
3. once this is done, you need to bind `mouse over event` to the slide. For each mouse over event, get the mouse position, and calculate its relative position compared with the position of the slide. Now you get the position of the mouse in our coordinate system.
4. now you have both the position of the mouse and center of the slide, you can easily find out whether the mouse is above the center, to the left of the center, and how far it is away from the center. If the mouse if above the center, move all three groups lower (you can use `transform` to move down the parent `div`). If the mouse is below the center, move all three groups higher. Same for left and right. Lets try to calculate the horizontal movement for example (vertical is the same):

```
//negative number means mouse is on the left, positive means it is on the right.
let mouseHorizontalDistance; 
//you can adjust this to decide how far you wanna move the elements
let k = 1.3;

let baseMoveDistance = -(mouseHorizontalDistance) * k;
let horizontalTextGroupMoveDistance = baseMoveDistance + "px";
//in the demo, the near triangles move further than text
let horizontalNearTrianglesGroupMoveDistance = baseMoveDistance * 1.1  + "px";
//and the far triangles move even further.
let horizontalFarTriangleGroupMoveDistance = baseMoveDistance * 1.3  + "px";

document.querySelector('#textGroup').style.transform = translate(vertical, horizontalTextGroupMoveDistance);

//do the same for near and far triangles.
```